# How can I enter 5M or 10k into AG Grid so it shows the full number (i.e. 5,000,000 or 10,000)

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Our users need quick and reliable data entry so they want to type 'M' into a number cell in AG Grid but have that converted into a number. e.g. 5M will become 5000.  I dont want to change the cell type to text or do a value formatter if at all possible as that then brings its own problems.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [Value Setter](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/value-setters/) to set the value to be entered into the cell after editing a cell

```
  {
    headerName: 'B',
    field: 'b',
    valueSetter: function (params) {
      const THOUSAND = 'k';
      const MILLION = 'm';
      const lastCharacter = params.newValue
        .charAt(params.newValue.length - 1)
        .toLowerCase();
      if (lastCharacter == THOUSAND) {
        var newValInt = parseInt(params.newValue) * 1000;
      } else if (lastCharacter == MILLION) {
        var newValInt = parseInt(params.newValue) * 1000000;
      } else {
        var newValInt = parseInt(params.newValue);
      }

      var valueChanged = params.data.b !== newValInt;
      if (valueChanged) {
        params.data.b = newValInt;
      }
      return valueChanged;
    },
  },
```

See this implemented in the following [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/7tFXDNbU5Aw8FWKz)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AdapTable with AG Grid then you can use the [Shortcut Module](https://docs.adaptabletools.com/docs/editing/shortcut-module).
This allows you to define shortcuts at design time or run time.
So in this case you would define a shortcut ('M' for Multiply by 1000) and then each time the user types 5M, AdapTable will convert it to 5,000 but the column will remain a numeric one.

```
Shortcut: {
 Shortcuts: [
  {
    Scope: { DataTypes: ['Number'] },
    ShortcutKey: 'M',
    ShortcutOperation: 'Multiply',
    ShortcutValue: 1000,
  },
  ],
},
```

Comment: yes we do use Adaptable so this works great for us.